# Why can't I pass an event to a function (SDL2)?

Tags: c, events, sdl, sdl-2

For some reasons when I pass the `event` to `playerObj_behavior` the `switch` inside my function isn't working when I hit SPACE while the switch inside `main` works just fine. All  was working when I still had the whole switch directly inside of main. What is happening ?

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void playerObj_behavior(SDL_Renderer * pRenderer, SDL_Event event)
{

    /*code*/
    if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
        case SDLK_SPACE: 
            pressTimer = SDL_GetTicks();
            moveRef = playerObj.pos.y;
            break;
        }
    }
    /*code*/
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /*code*/
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    switch (event.type)
    {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        keepExe = 0;
        break;
    }

    playerObj_behavior(pRenderer, event);
    /*code*/
}
```

**EDIT** : Passing `SDL_Keycode *sym` instead of `SDL_Event event` make the sprite react to me pressing space but it's all buggy and unconsistent with the movement formula.

When I copy/paste my code function into main and fuse the switches all works just fine. What the heck is going on ?

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't work. Unless, your SDL_PollEvent() call is in a while loop and the playerObj_behavior() is outside the loop.

Comment: I don't understand then I'm wasting so much time on that :/, Maybe I should pass the event as a pointer ? But I'm a bit lost should I use `event->type` and `event->key.keysym.sym` if I do so ?

Comment: Use `event.type` in the main() and If you pass it as a pointer, then  `event->key.keysym.sym` in the playerObj_behavior()

Comment: ok thank you for your help, if you say the event isn't the problem it means the problem is eslsewhere, I think it's `moveRef = playerObj.pos.y;`
I assigned `playerObj.pos = (SDL_Rect) { .x = number, .y = number, .w = number, .h = number };` earlier in `main` so is it correct to call `playerObj.pos.y;` later on ?

Comment: Initializing a variable like you mentioned, doesn't causes any memory corruption, unless the `moveRef` variable and the `pos.y` are different data types. And as per assigning the `playerObj.pos`  you should write a proper function to init each and every field of `pos` variable.Is playerObj a global?

Comment: well yeah I declared it at root level, I think it's the `event` pass that is buggy because I just copied/pasted my function into main and it's working just fine. Maybe it's like quantum mechanic once you peek inside SDL_KEYDOWN it gets destroyed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58075/discussion-between-wicelo-and-askmish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the culprit, externalizing the function was also making some variables local so they where initialized every turn of main loop. I externalized those functions into my object structure and now everything working just fine. I need to get GDB to work on windows so I can find those problem quicker.